# Is it true that using Microsoft Virtual PC 2007, you can copy the .vhd file (about 2GB) and you have "a new computer"?

Tags: virtual-machine, microsoft-virtual-pc

Is it true that using Microsoft Virtual PC 2007, you can copy the .vhd file (about 2GB) and you have "a new computer"?

For example, if you make several folders on your real physical PC

```
c:\xp01  
c:\xp02  
c:\xp03
```

and now, each one containing the .vhd file (about 2GB), then you are like having 3 computers all installed with XP to boot up, install software, and shut down, just like a real PC?

And when you don't want any of those PC, you can just delete that folder, and that's it.

If you like that state of a computer (the software installed, bookmarks, etc), you can shut down that virtual PC, copy that folder to

```
c:\xp_good
```

and you will have a new virtual PC with that exact setting.  And when you want a new virtual PC, then you can just copy that to

```
c:\xp_good_01
```

and you can use that virtual PC until if you don't want it any more, delete that folder, and repeat the step of copying c:\xp_good again to another folder, and you will have a brand new virtual PC?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

yes, this is true.

you can use virtual machines as 'disposable computers' for added security, i.e. destroy the VHD after each online banking session or financial transaction and restore the clean backup disk image. virtual machines are also popular as test platforms for new software (if limited graphics power is not an issue).

this is also true for other virtualization software such as VirtualBox or VMware or Parallel.

p.s.: [VHD Attach](http://www.jmedved.com/default.aspx?page=vhdattach) makes mounting virtual disks in Windows 7 a lot easier.

Comment: VirtualPC has an option called "Undo disks", enabling them for a VM would make the above a lot easier.

Comment: This is even more powerful with the Ultimate version of Windows 7 which supports booting directly into a .vhd file.